# Pending transactions

Tags: transactions, wallet

Does anybody know what is going on with transactions that have a delay of 3 to 4 days for arrival to its destination address? I sent some bitcoins to Coinable from my Desktop wallet but it has not yet been confirmed. Please let me know if anybody knows anything.

Thank you.